# Laravel: Test not Using Mocked Method

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8, mockery

I want `getNumber` to return `200` in the test case, but when I run the test and inspect the result with `$response->dump()` I can see that the mock is not overriding the method as it is showing `array:1 [0 => 100]`. What am I missing?

Controller:

```
class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function fetch(Request $request)
    {
        $service = new Service();
    
        return [$service->getNumber()];
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public function getNumber(): int
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
class ControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFetchGetsNumber()
    {
        $mock = $this->partialMock(Service::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('getNumber')->andReturn(200);
        });
    
        $response = $this->post('/api/controller');
        $response->dump(); // returns 100 but should return 200...
    }
}
```

I am using Laravel 8 and referencing this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#mocking-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Laravel` you have to use the container to mock classes.

```
$service = resolve(Service::class);
```

In constructors or handle methods, if you inject your classes there it will automatically use the container. If put into constructors or classes, remember the resolution of the class with the constructor, have to use the container.

```
class Job 
{
    public function handle(Service $service)
    {
        // will use the mocked service.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not exactly following how to use the container to mock the class. Are you saying that I should be calling resolve() inside of the test?

Comment: No, in your class in your laravel app, if you do not use the container, it will not use the mocked class when calling the code.

$this->mock() or  $this->partialMock() binds it to the container already.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your "Service" is not registered to the Service Container.

Inside `AppServiceProvider.php` make sure to registered the "service" you want to bind.

```
$this->instance->bind('service', ... );
```

In your Controller, instead of instantiating the class with the `new` keyword, use Laravel's `app()->make('service')`.

This will allow you to Mock the class in your Unit Test. Inside your Test case..

```
 $this->app->bind('Service', $mock);
```